# Error on load image on React-native: Unexpected character

Tags: react-native

I'm try display a image on a component on React-native, but I don't know why this error happens...

Example of code:

```
render () {
    let { convenience } = this.props
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 50}}>
        <Text style={{marginRight: 30}}>{convenience.name}</Text>
        <Image source={require('./icons___favorito_ativo.png')} />
      </View>
    )
}
```

Printscreen:

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I too faced the same error. After a lot of trying, I restarted the packager, and the app picked up the image. So the solution is: Restart the packager.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also close the Packager window, running the cmd 'react-native run-ios' was not enough in my case. This issue come up after upgrading from RN 0.19 to RN 0.23.1, not sure if this was the origin.

Comment: Needed to do this after running `react-native link` in order to install LinearGradient. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Currently an open issue with React Native:  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6691.  Highly annoying - Reloading the app and/or restarting the package manager is, for now, the only solution I currently am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

That happened to me many times with images exported from sketch, it's weird.

I don't know why, but after exporting the same image from photoshop the error disappeared.

Comment: The same happened to me. Sketch exported images don't work. Replacing them with images exported via other graphic apps helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had a spaces in my directory name. To fix it I just used another directory.

Changed

...\Desktop\develop (test)\MyProject...

to

...\Desktop\develop\MyProject...

Comment: my case ...\Desktop\[myname]\MyProject.. i had  ' [ ' , ' ] '

Answer (score 0):

I know this is going sound pretty weird, but I'm going to add this comment in case anybody else gets here. I created a index.ios.js file by copying a simple example from something online at https://rnplay.org   I kept getting "unexpected character" errors. I'm using Atom.io as my script tool. I was thinking perhaps I had an encoding issue with the wrong character set. I've confirmed I'm using UTF-8

So I was using the (left/right) arrow keys on my keyboard, and I notice the cursor would stop moving for two keyboard arrow pushes, right at the location identified in my Emulator Red Screen of Disaster. It was like there were two invisible characters in my code. I played with this for a pretty long time to confirm. I was able to highlight the "hidden" characters and delete them.

After deletion, the new code works great.

Bizarre. Not sure what was there. (Note: I copied the Slider Example Code from https://rnplay.org/apps/5FsfPA and I used a "Select All" and Command-C to do the copying and Command-V to paste... if anybody wants to repeat the experiment)

And yes, I know how silly this sounds. Perhaps others have hit the same issue?  The verification test is pretty easy.  Start at the location identified by the Red screen error message.  Use the keyboard arrow and verify the cursor on your text moves for each key push.

Comment: you can see irregular space characters with good editors like sublime text or with linters like eslint.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error but just with android. 
And the problem was in `ios` suffix:

Filename was `back-icon@4x.ios.png`

Then in code:

```
export const backButton = require('../../images/back-icon@4x.ios.png');
```

When I remove the suffix in filename and in code ( to `'../../images/back-icon@4x.png'`) error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The solution that worked for me was to remove "_" on image's filename and finally hot reload your application.